# Form not submitting, it just redirects me to the domainname/form.php

Tags: php, html

I just can't seem to figure out why this form is not submitting. It is a simple contact form that I am trying to build.

html:

```
<div class="contact-container" id="contact">
  <div class="contact-wrapper">
    <form method="post" action="form.php">
      <h2>Contact Us</h2>
      <input type="name" placeholder="Name and Surname" required />
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email" required />
      <textarea type="message" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
      <input class="submit" type="submit" placeholder="submit" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

php:

```
if(isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] != '') {
   
 if( filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
     
     $name = $_POST['name'];
     $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
     $message = $_POST['message'];

     $email_subject = "New Form Submission";
     $email_body = "User Name: $name.\n".
               "User Email: $visitor_email.\n\n". 
               "User Message: $message\n";
     $to = "info@goldberylmedia.com"; 
     $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
     $headers = "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n"; 

     mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers); 

      header ("Location: ../index.html");
      
      echo '<script> alert("Message received. We will get back to you soon.") </script>'; 
      
 }

}
```

And I am also trying to make an alert that the message has been sent, but that hasn't been working either.

Thanks for the help in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2):

`<input type="email" placeholder="Email" required />`

is missing the `name="email"` attribute. It should be

`<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required />`.

Your other fields are missing their `name` attribute as well. So your updated code should be:

```
<div class="contact-container" id="contact">
  <div class="contact-wrapper">
    <form method="post" action="form.php">
      <h2>Contact Us</h2>
      <input type="name" name="name" placeholder="Name and Surname" required />
      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required />
      <textarea type="message" name="message" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
      <input class="submit" type="submit" placeholder="submit" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

`type="name"` is meaningless on an `<input>` field, and defaults to `type="text"`.

Also, `type="message"` is meaningless on a `<textarea>` field, and can be removed.

As for the alert, you can't add code after a `header('Location...')` redirect because the browser will ignore the content and just redirect before showing the page content. Better to redirect to a PHP page and add a query string like this:

```
header( 'Location: thanks.php?message=alert' );
exit();
```

and in `thanks.php`:

```
if ( isset($_GET['message']) && $_GET['message'] == 'alert' ) {
      echo '<script> alert("Message received. We will get back to you soon.") </script>'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add name attribute with fields. Because **only form elements with a name attribute will have their values passed when submitting a form.**

So add name attributes in your fields.

```
<input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name and Surname" required />
<input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required />
<textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
<input class="submit" type="submit" placeholder="submit" />
```